# Running multiple instances of apache with Flash Media Server

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, adobe-flash

Trying to get Adobe FMS server up and running - having multiple problems...

(all on a rackspace cloud server running Centos 5.5)

Trying to use a flash application I purchased to record video from webcam to the server

http://activeden.net/item/webcam-recorder/236757

Client purchased a license for FMS - so I install FMS with the license (putting it in production mode)

In production mode, when I try to record, I get an access denied - it took like 3 days to find out that I had to create a folder in the applications folder, give user FMS access to this folder and record to that. This only works if I install FMS without a license putting it in developer mode

If I'm in developer mode and record, it records fine, but if I choose not to install the version of Apache that comes with FMS and use mine that I'm using for the rest of the website, It doesn't record (even though I'm doing all of this through rtmp:// not http://)

All I need FMS for is to record from webcam and produce the video for viewing

Should I run FMS on its own server, put the webserver in its allow list and deny everything else?

How do I / can I configure FMS to work with another installation / instance of Apache?

There is still the issue of it being in developer mode and not production - is this an issue or can it stay in developer mode so long as I take all my normal security precautions? (closing ports, etc... I'll fully pen test the server before going live)

I'm not expecting a terrible amount of load. It's for students in a very specific industry. I don't mind spining up another server just for it.